# Java- Help with writing sudoko

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a Sudoko in java.

(there a Gui class that prints the matrix).

Here's an example for 2 methods that I wrote regarding the rows of the matrix(9X9).

When there's "-1" in a cell the method puts there a number that does not appear in the spesific row and if there is already a number it is update a boolean array to "true" in the place of the index that equales to the number (number can be between 1-9).

It stops after 4 loops, and I'm having a really hard time to realize why.

Can someone see what is wrong? Maybe a mistake of understanding something?

```
public static boolean checkRow(int row, int[][] matr) {
    boolean[] ind = new boolean[9];
    Arrays.fill(ind, false);
    for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
        if (matr[row][j] == -1) {

            int n = whatToputRow(row, matr);

            if (n == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                matr[row][j] = n;
                ind[n - 1] = true;
                System.out.print(n+" ");
            }
        } else {
            ind[matr[row][j] - 1] = true;
        }
    }

    return checkBoolean(ind);
}



    public static boolean checkBoolean(boolean[] mat) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        if (!mat[i]) {

            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


    public static int whatToputRow(int row, int[][] mat) {

    for (int number = 1; number <= 9; number++) {
        boolean bool = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (!bool && i <= 8) {
            if (mat[row][i] == number) {
                bool = true;
            } else {
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        if (bool == false)
            return number;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does the `whatToputRow` function do?

Comment: Without seeing all your code, I'm guessing that whatToputRow(row, matr) is returning 0, which causes your method to return false and therefore stop executing.  You should try stepping through your code.

Comment: oh soory, I'll add it. it finds which number I can add so that it will be still ligeal.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `whatToPutRow()` returns 0 after the 4th iteration. As you are returning false on that condition the loop will stop running.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. why do you suspect that?

Comment: Because it's the only way I see the loop breaking. What is your inital setup?

Comment: just a simple class that opens a window where you put into the values.

Comment: OK I don't have java right now but try printing out your matrix after each iteration in checkRow and bool, number and i in whatToPutRow. I'm sure you'll find out that it is returning 0 somewhere. I can't see where though on a quick glance.